# Initial connection very slow

Tags: linux, centos, networking

I have a client that came to be with a system where every initial connection was very slow.  if you load the web server it can take a while to load. If you SSH into the server it seems to hang as well. My initial assumption was that it was DNS related. I checked DNS and it looks OK. The dig command get's back a response right away. Memory, CPU, Load, Disk etc. all look OK. While on the box I noticed that every time I did a connection for a host the first time it was very slow and then every time there after it was fast. For instance if I did `curl cnn.com`. It took a few seconds. The next time it happened real fast. I suspected DNS so I did it to an IP and got the same result. It was not session specific since looking at the traffic with tcpdump showed a new source port. What I noticed over and over was that it had to do with the destination IP. Once there was a connection to that IP all other connections to the same IP went fast. Looking at a capture of the network traffic there were multiple re-transmissions before we got a response. Any idea what would cause this? You can see the traffic captured here https://ufile.io/f/taoop

Comment: Does your clients system live behind a firewall of some kind which wants to do a reverse DNS lookup for logging purposes?

Comment: Not that I saw. Also we saw the same issues when connecting locally on the same lan. I did a tcpdump on all traffic at the time of the request and saw nothing other than my request and the DNS lookup

Comment: Does the issue only happen with TCP, e.g. does ping show the same effect? Maybe using a `traceroute` command which can use tcp rather than icmp and a higher number of queries than normal might give some insight. I haven't looked at your pcap files (sorry) - they might show pmtu discovery,